# How to Input a time series set of data into MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to create a database with time series data in MS Access 2010. More specifically, I have order history over 30 months.

What is the most efficient way to input this into MS Access? Currently, I have part number in the first column and months going across the first row. Is this the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe give us a bit more info about what you have now and what you want to achieve? We don't know your subject area at all...

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more detail, the best approach is to create normalized tables.  That means that you create a separate table, perhaps named [Order History], with one column named [Part Number] and another named [Order Date].  In this table, you create a new row for every order.

If you later desire to see "months going across the first row", then you can use Cross-Tab queries (a.k.a. SQL Transform queries) to represent your data differently for various reports.